# Do not show X (clear button) in prop_search?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, operator, panel

I'm making an operator that uses the UNDO panel.

In that panel, I'm showing a `prop_search` to select a vertex group:
[image]

**The problem:**

I've found that X button that appears to clear the selected option calls `bpy.ops.ui.button_string_clear()` ([API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.ui.html#bpy.ops.ui.button_string_clear)). **That causes my panel to close** when I press it. (I guess is because its calling different operator than mine).

I'd like to get rid of that X if possible (I could implement the same function with a property that won't make the panel close).

So, anyone knows if its possible? Or is there any other way to avoid my panel to close?

Thank you so much for the help and any idea :)