# string property with subtype "DIR_PATH" crashes blender after clicking accept on the file browser it opens

Tags: python, interface

i tried copy pasting other peoples code and it still crashes even tho nothing is being done with that path

this is a batch exporter that worked perfectly fine before that line, how can i make the user select a path to export to?

no matter what even with everything commented out the file browser this line opens always causes a crash

```
UserExportPath : bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Path", subtype="DIR_PATH")
```

Code:

```
import bpy
import os

class Alx_PT_PLYExport(bpy.types.Panel):
    """"""

    bl_label = "Batch Export Selection"
    bl_idname = "alx_panel_ply_export"

    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_category = "Alx Export"

    

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return True
    
    def draw(self, context):
        AlxLayout = self.layout
        AxlOPS_PLY_Export = AlxLayout.row().operator(Alx_OT_BatchPLYExport.bl_idname, text="Export Stanford (.ply)")

class Alx_OT_BatchPLYExport(bpy.types.Operator):
    """"""

    bl_label = "Batch Export Selection"
    bl_idname = "alx.operator_ply_export"

    UseAsciiFormat : bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Export as ASCII", default=False)
    UseMeshModifiers : bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Export with Mesh Modifiers", default=False)
    UseVertexNormals : bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Export Vertex Normals", default=False)
    UseUVCoordinates : bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Export UV Coordinates", default=False)
    UseVertexColors : bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Export Vertex Colors", default=False)
    ExportGlobalScale : bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Export Scale", default=1.0, min=-100000, max=100000)

    UserExportPath : bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Path", subtype="DIR_PATH")

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return context.area.type == "VIEW_3D"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        # try:
        #     ObjectListToExport = []
        #     context.selected_objects[0]
        #     for Object in context.selected_objects:
        #         if (Object is not None) and (Object.type == "MESH"):
        #             ObjectListToExport.append(Object)

        #     for ExportObject in ObjectListToExport:
        #         blend_file_path = bpy.data.filepath
        #         if (blend_file_path != ""):
        #             directory = os.path.dirname(blend_file_path)
        #             target_file = os.path.join(directory, "%s.ply" % ExportObject.name)

        #             for DataObject in bpy.data.objects:
        #                 DataObject.select_set(False)


        #             ExportObject.select_set(True)
        #             bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ExportObject

        #             bpy.ops.export_mesh.ply(
        #                 filepath=target_file, 
        #                 use_selection=True, 
        #                 use_ascii=self.UseAsciiFormat, 
        #                 use_mesh_modifiers=self.UseMeshModifiers, 
        #                 use_normals=self.UseVertexNormals, 
        #                 use_uv_coords=self.UseUVCoordinates, 
        #                 use_colors=self.UseVertexColors,
        #                 global_scale=self.ExportGlobalScale
        #                 )

        # except Exception as e:
        #     print(e)

        return {"FINISHED"}
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self, width=300)


AlxClassQueue = [Alx_OT_BatchPLYExport, Alx_PT_PLYExport]

def register():
    for AlxQCls in AlxClassQueue:
        bpy.utils.register_class(AlxQCls)

    bpy.context.preferences.use_preferences_save = True

def unregister():
    for AlxQCls in AlxClassQueue:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(AlxQCls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: AFAIK it opens a file browser which clears the current temporary panel. Similar to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/309664/do-not-show-x-clear-button-in-prop-search eg it's technically possible to do it but it's not designed to work

Comment: thank you for the answer, i saw a few similar posts but didn't find a specific reason of why, now i know, hopefully passing a string path to it then should work if done from a NPanel